# Назначение классов в зависимости от выбранного пункта меню

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет!

Есть идея сделать 1 страницу html, но с разным контентом.

Суть в том, чтоб на страницу разместить сразу весь контент, а при выборе пунктов меню просто в некоторых элементах менять класс видимости и таким образом переключать отображаемый контент на странице.

Собственно просьба: помогите со скриптом, который изменяет класс самого выбранного элемента li меню на active и назначает классы произвольным элементам дом.

Нашел скрипт, но он не работает для таких ссылок, а в js не силен...

Меню использовать буду такое:

```js
    window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    var myLinks = document.querySelectorAll("#menu a");
    for(var i=0; i<myLinks.length; i++)
      if(location.href==myLinks[i].href){
      myLinks[i].parentNode.classList.add("active");
      }
    });
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#1"><div class="miN"></div><span class="mt">{{LMN1}}</span><span class="mb">{{LMN2}}</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#2"><div class="miS"></div><span class="mt">{{LMS1}}</span><span class="mb">{{LMS2}}</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#3"><div class="miC"></div><span class="mt">{{LMC1}}</span><span class="mb">{{LMC2}}</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#4"><div class="miM"></div><span class="mt">{{LMSc1}}</span><span class="mb">{{LMSc2}}</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрые люди помогли! Вопрос закрыт.
Делюсь, может кому то пригодится:

```js
var IDs = {"#a":["#nC"],"#b":["#sC"],"#c":["#cC"], "#d":["#scC"]}
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", updPage);
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", updPage);
    
// Обновление элементов меню и страницы
function addCls(arr,add){
  arr.forEach(function(id){
    var blc = document.querySelector(id);
    blc && blc.classList[add]("active");
  });
}
function updPage() {
  var temp = [];
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("#menu a"), function(link,i){
    var id = link.hash;
    id = IDs[id] ? [id].concat(IDs[id]) : [id];
    var yes = location.href == link.href || !location.hash && !i;
    var add = yes ? "add" : "remove";
    link.parentNode.classList[add]("active");
    yes ? (temp = id) : addCls(id, add);
  });
  addCls(temp,"add");
}
```

```css
.blc{display:none;}
.blc.active{display:block;}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#a">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c">item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d">item4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
  <div id="content">
  <div id="nC" class="blc">item1 - Этот контент в Div-е nC</div>
  <div id="sC" class="blc">item2 - Этот контент в Div-е sC</div>
  <div id="cC" class="blc">item3 - Этот контент в Div-е cC</div>
  <div id="scC" class="blc">item4 - Этот контент в Div-е scC</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Советую все-таки выучить хотябы основы JS и JQuery хотябы. С помощью них можно сделать, просто используя стандартные функции.
Например для первой ссылки сделать что-то типа:

```
$('li:first').focus(function(){тут опишы все что нужно спрятать или показать});
```

Способ конечно тривиальный, но как для новичка я думаю пойдёт...